# Rails app sending javascript to client when loading whole page, but not when clicking link_to root_path?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

When I refresh my Rails app or press enter on localhost:3000 in the browser, my app loads
'/' correctly and displays to the console

```
Started GET "/assets/*"
```

for all assets my app has to send.

But when I click a link which is produced from

```
link_to root_path
```

it displays the GET '/' in the console correctly, but it does not do a GET on all the assets,
thus causing all elements on the webpage which use my javascript to not work.

How can I remedy this?

Edit: Using rails version 4.1.6

Comment: Which version of Rails?

Comment: Ok; did you try out the answer I provided related to Turbolinks then? Without other information present this is likely what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what limited information has been provided in the question, I believe that you are likely on Rails 4 and this is due to Turbolinks.

If you want to disable turbolinks you can follow the following steps

1. Remove the gem 'turbolinks' line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the //= require turbolinks from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
3. Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
4. Place   = javascript_include_tag 'application' at the bottom of application.html
5. Place = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'all' at the top of application.css in the head tag

These steps are outlined by Steve Klabnik here [Removing Turbolinks from Rails 4](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4)

---

The following is not a direct answer to your question, but some additional elaboration on Turbolinks.

The intent of Turbolinks is to decrease page reload times by not requiring the browser to recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change.  By default a new Rails 4 application is opted-in to this.  Since the JavaScript is not reloaded on every request you can no longer use your standard `DOMContentLoaded` or `jQuery.ready()` methods of triggering your code.

Turbolinks fires supplemental events on document that you would need to opt-in to instead, such as `page:load`

For more complete information if you are interested in going this direction you can view additional details in the [turbolinks github repo](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

Comment: This worked thank you. Is there a rationale why turbolinks makes sense for enough applications to make it default given how popular various uses of javascript are that respond to and deal with events?

Comment: Turbolinks is a rather controversial feature in Rails 4, with people falling on the for or against side of things. Nice Twitter complaint thread here on the topic `https://twitter.com/tomdale/status/278917111223558144`. There are some performance boosts to be had with Turbolinks if you can use them. It's disabled in my projects as I'm using JavaScript MVC frameworks that it doesn't play well with, as well as using Gon to deliver some data payloads via JavaScript.  Other than because DHH wants it that way I can't say why it's there by default. This is worth a read `http://bit.ly/1pMchm31`